# Send HTML Email With Attachments PHP

Tags: php, email

I came across a situation where I needed to send HTML email with attachments.
In the past I had sent HTML email, but sending HTML email with attachments was something I couldn't find easily. 
So this is how I tackled it.

Let me show you my form first. 
[image: On this Form user can fill in his details and can attach a Resume]

This is the Code for my Form (its using Bootstrap)

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="career.php" method="post" data-parsley-validate="">
  <div class="row m-t-25">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" name="fname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 marginttop">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" name="lname" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row  m-t-10">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No" name="phone" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 marginttop">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Id" name="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row  m-t-10">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Education" name="education" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 marginttop">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Work Experience" name="experience" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row m-t-10">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Department Applying For  " name="dept" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6  marginttop">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="validatedCustomFile" name="my_file" required>

      <label class="custom-file-label  m-l-15" for="validatedCustomFile">  Attach CV...</label>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!--
                                                    <div class="row m-t-10">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Captcha Text  ">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 p-l-30 marginttop">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">S0Frt</button>

                                                        </div>


                                                    </div> -->

  <div class="row m-t-10">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">
      <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active blue-light-bg-color capital-text fontsize-16" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Apply Now</a>-->
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Apply Now1</button>

    </div>



  </div>

</form>
```

After user clicks on **Apply Now**, I wanted the data to be mailed to an email address along with attached file.

Now, as you can see at `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="career.php" method="post" data-parsley-validate="">` that the form is submitting to itself. So I wrote the following code on the top of my .*PHP* file

```html
<?php
if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){ 
//var_dump($_POST); 
//die; $
fname = $_POST['fname']; 
$lname = $_POST['lname']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$education = $_POST['education']; 
$experience = $_POST['experience']; 
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$message = '
<table width="70%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="height: 129px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#6b9e19" align="center" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; height: 21px;"><b>Resume From Website.</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td width="30%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #7a7a7a; height: 18px;"><b>First Name</b></td>
      <td width="70%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #404040; height: 18px;"><b>' . $fname . '</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td width="30%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #7a7a7a; height: 18px;"><b>Last Name</b></td>
      <td width="70%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #404040; height: 18px;"><b>' . $lname . '</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td width="30%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #7a7a7a; height: 18px;"><b>Mobile </b></td>
      <td width="70%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #404040; height: 18px;"><b>' . $phone . '</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td width="30%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #7a7a7a; height: 18px;"><b>Email</b></td>
      <td width="70%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #404040; height: 18px;"><b>' . $email . '</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td width="30%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #7a7a7a; height: 18px;"><b>Education</b></td>
      <td width="70%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #404040; height: 18px;"><b>' . $education . '</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td width="30%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #7a7a7a; height: 18px;"><b>Work Experience </b></td>
      <td width="70%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #404040; height: 18px;"><b>' . $experience . '</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 18px;">
      <td width="30%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #7a7a7a; height: 18px;"><b>Dept. Applying For </b></td>
      <td width="70%" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align: left; color: #404040; height: 18px;"><b>' . $dept . '</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>'; 
$from_email         = 'career@onecompaany.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts
    $recipient_email    = 'amit@othercompany.com'; //recipient email (most cases it is your personal email)
    
    //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them,
    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["fname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
    $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
    //$subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get subject from HTML form
    $subject        = "Resume From Website";
    
    //Get uploaded file data
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    
    $file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

    if($file_error > 0)
    {
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
    }
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
    //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";
       
        //plain text
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));
       
        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= $encoded_content;
   
    $sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {      
        //die('Thank you for your email');
        echo "<script langauge='javascript'>alert ('Your Resume sent successfully. We will contact soon'); </script>";
    }else{
        die('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.');  
    }
  
}
?>
```

Now, when the user clicks on **Apply Now** Button, the intended party specified in `$recipient_email` gets the email as follows:
[image]

Comment: There's too many variants of that horrid manual MIME/multipart construction code floating around already. People are better off using SwiftMailer/PHPMailer for that.

Comment: The unattributed origin of above snippet is: https://www.sanwebe.com/2011/01/send-php-mail-with-attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I wanted to share this code snippet with community, I thought if I click on Answer your question, this question will get posted just as a topic. But let it be,

I hope other users might find it useful.

Comment: You mean this is not an actual question you want to ask? You completely miss understood what this place is for?

Comment: Yes.. I accept that it was my mistake.. But now I got it!

Comment: I suggest you simply delete this "question" ;-)